# Fine Uploader - how do I setup paste handling after reset() is called?

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using this to initialize a new FineUploader instance:

```
this.uploader = new FineUploader({
  element: this.fileUpload.nativeElement,
  template: 'qq-simple-thumbnails-template',
  form: {
    interceptSubmit: false
  },
  paste: {
    targetElement: this.fileUpload.nativeElement
  }
});
```

I should mention I am using Angular so I am accessing the container through @ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload.

Template(very similar to default):

```
<div style="visibility: hidden" id="qq-simple-thumbnails-template">
  <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop or Paste Files Here">
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
      <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
      <div>Upload a file</div>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
      <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
      <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
      <li>
        <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
          <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
        <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
        <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
        <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
        <span class="pull-right">
          <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
          <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
          <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Remove</button>
          <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
      <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
      <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
      </div>
    </dialog>
    <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
      <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
      <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </dialog>
    <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
      <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
      <input type="text">
      <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </dialog>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to reset the files that have been uploaded to the library and the only way I have found that worked is using this.uploader.reset(). I tried looping through what was returned from getUploads() and using the ids to then call removeFileRef(id) and that did not remove them from the UI.

The issue is once I call reset() the paste handling is removed and not added back. It seems to be on purpose: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/master/client/js/paste.js#L44

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, without maintainers' support it is impossible to properly reset paste handler.

However, we can hack fineuploader's implementation, thanks to JavaScript's dynamic nature.

```
const old = qq.PasteSupport
   if (old) {
        qq.PasteSupport = function (o) {
        var self = this
        old.call(self, o)
        self.reset = function() {}
   }
}
```

I believe current reset behavior of pasteHandler is a wrong fix for https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1293.

The original issue 1293 is that the user removes the paste target element but cannot remove the handler. However, `reset` doesn't imply users will remove the paste target. They should call, ideally, the `destroy` method of fine uploader instead of `reset`. But fine-uploader doesn't have such method at all!